# Can't INSERT values into tables

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-key-relationship, sql-insert

I have 3 tables in MySQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE bank(
idBank int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
nameBank varchar(50)
);
CREATE TABLE region(
idRegion int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
address varchar(50) NOT NULL,
district varchar(30) NOT NULL,
city varchar(50) NOT NULL,
tel varchar(15) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE branch(
idBranch int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
idBank int(11) NOT NULL,
idRegion int(11) NOT NULL,
quantity int(50) NULL,
president varchar(60) NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (idBank) REFERENCES bank (idBank),
FOREIGN KEY (idRegion) REFERENCES region (idRegion)
);
```

When I try to INSERT values into tables, it works for first two, but not recording into branch table. Why?

Comment: Where is your INSERT code?

Comment: Provide some code please, we are not augurs to tell what is wrong with yours

Comment: Pls make sure idBank and idRegion you are trying to insert branch are there in corresponding bank and region tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you try to insert, and what error do you get?
Since your tables have foreign key constraints, it means that you cannot insert a new line into these tables where the value for the foreign key does not exist in the referenced table.
In English: You cannot add a record in the branch table if there is no corresponding bank to which it belongs, same goes for region.